# C++ input value process as math function

Tags: c++

I’m very new in C++ and I need your help. I want to use the input value as a mathematical function then print the result.

What i need is:

> When user input: 2 +1 and hit Enter then output (cout>>)
>   should be your result is: 3 (the sum of 2 + 1)

The mathematical symbol could be + or * or / or -.

Could you please help me with some example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because I'm feeling nice today, [see this blog of mine](https://ghost.pileborg.se/2016/10/08/simple-stack-based-operator-precedence-parser/). There is also actual code [in a GitHub repository](https://github.com/pileon/OperatorPrecedenceEval). The code should be well-commented. However, parsing and evaluation is still not something a "very new" programmer should jump straight into. I suggest you find some books or tutorials first.

Comment: I’m sure that this comment will be removed and I don't know who voted with negative value my question, but just want to say to give negative vote for a question will not make you more intelligent.
Many people are not experts and need help and they can ask very simple (from expert’s points of view)
questions, and I'm sure it is not because I want to offend someone.
It is not very honest, we have to keep being human in all situations.
Thanks for all, will not post here again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "Reverse Polish notation" and implementation in C++

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.